# Attaching click event to boostrap typeahead template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, dom-events

I'm using the [angular bootstrap typeahead with a custom template](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead). It works pretty well for doing what I want with my custom template, however I cannot use `ngClick` to attach a function to clicking on an item. How can I do that?

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
  <a ng-click="testFn();">
    <span ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
  </a>
</script>
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/mezipuhuju/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: use typeahead-on-select($item, $model, $label, $event) for performing the event. When a item is clicked, select event will fire..

Comment: is one of those supposed to be the name of a `$scope` method?

Comment: yes, such as $scope.amethod=function ($item, $model, $label, $event){ ... };